# OnPropertyChanged exception when trying to get sitecore items using TDS

Tags: tds

I have an existing project. When right clicking any folder in my content folder and pressing get sitecore items (selecting all children in there) I get the following error in the Team Development for Sitecore output:

```
Exception OnPropertyChanged must be called on the UI thread. (COMException):
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread(String callerMemberName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.OrderableProject.OnPropertyChanged(UInt32 itemid, Int32 propid, UInt32 flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.HierarchyNode.ReDraw(UIHierarchyElement element)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreItemNode.RefreshItemInProject()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreItemNode.RefreshSitecoreInfo(String sitecoreItemPath)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreItemNode.RefreshSitecoreInfo()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.GetItemStatus.GetItem(CheckedSitecoreItem item, Dictionary`2 createdNodes)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.GetItemStatus.GetItemsWorker()
```

The UI shows the following:

[image]

I am using

- Visual Studio 2019 (as admin)
- TDS 6.0.0.14
- Sitecore 7.2

Tried googling it, but none of the results for that error where TDS related.

I have done a right click + quick push items before attempting this. Not sure if this could have any effect.

Comment: I have the same thing. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround this issue by selecting the `Sync with Sitecore` option and pulling my content into the project that way.

[image: Sync with Sitecore]